# git& source control pending changes& green marks on the right in vscode

Tags: git, github, version-control, pull-request, vscode-remote

[image]

First time to use the remote server, and somehow all turned green after I inputed the `git init`.

I am tring to use git pulll to download the file from github

Anybody who can explanid how to handle it?

Comment: Git init creates a new local repository with git. You can still set up a remote for it, but usually you'll simply run `git clone` first.